# Automate downloading of pictures in web browser and their convert into pdf format using python

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

I have website where I need to download some stuff (png pictures). 
The process goes like this.

Go to website -> login with credentials -> open needed content -> copy image link address -> paste it in notepad -> click on next button -> copy image link address -> paste it in notepad. And iteratively repeat until I can't click next button. From generated links inside notepad I can download images and after from images make PDF book. I manage to download all pictures using urllib and also to make PDF from pictures with PIL library.

OK what I manage to make is with help of selenium webdriver and python, I can login on my website, click on links to came on my desired popup window where I can scrape content I need. But here I have problem because when I get popup window I can handle him with command `driver.switch_to.window.(window_handle)`. After when I enter css_selector I get error:

> selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such
>   element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css
>   selector","selector":"li.buttonSpace:nth-child(3)"}

OK my question is, even if I solve this problem with locating necessary element how I can scan website and look for img element? Also with selenium or some other library?

Comment: Using an official API could be much, much easier.  Have you checked for an API?

Comment: Stack Overflow works best for single questions, where there is a Minimum. Complete, Verifiable, Example that you provide and others can tinker with.  As written, this may be too broad.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation, as suggested when you created this account.  [On topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and [... the perfect question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) apply here.
StackOverflow is not a design, coding, research, or tutorial resource.

Comment: @Paul- you mean on selenium API?

Comment: Too much code. Break your code into pieces and identify what is your problem. Describe it and what you tried and people will be more than happy to help! See [mcve].

Comment: @AntonvBR -  thanks for advice

Comment: Ok I came to conclusion that I need access to a frame inside popup window, and I found how to access with switch_to.frame. And now I am getting error "no such element: Unable to locate element". Does anybody know what could be a problem? I tried to find elements by css selector, class name and xpath. Line of code I enter after for loop in my example.
element = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector(".navbar-header")
element.click()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem:), problem was that I had frame inside frame.

So solution is:

```
driver.switch_to.frame(driver.find_element_by_xpath("frame_level_1"))
driver.switch_to.frame(driver.find_element_by_xpath("frame_level_2"))
element = driver.find_element_by_xpath("Desired button").click()
```